# UWP .Net POSPrinter Not Identifying Epson USB Receipt Printer

Tags: uwp, usb, epson, posprinter, pointofservice

I am following the example from the following Repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PosPrinter.

In the Scenario1_ReceiptPrinter.xaml.cs I have modified the FindReceiptPrinter to run a FindAllAsync() like below:

```
 DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
```

When running the function that way versus passing in a device selector I am able to find the device ID which matches the printer SymbolicName in my Registry for the installed printer.  However, the printer object is always null even when I explicitly pass in the printer Id.

I'm not sure if there is an issue with the way my printer is installed or if I need to call it differently when it is a USB Printer.  Below are some screen shots of my modified code for debugging purposes:

Device Collection Populated:

[image: Device Collection Populated]

Printer Found:

[image: Printer Found]

Printer Object Null:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official document, USB connected printers are currently not supported.

> Support is currently limited to the Network and Bluetooth device models listed in the tables below. USB connected printers are currently not supported. Please check back for additional support to be added in the future.
>
> [image]

For mor info, please see [**Device support**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-printer#device-support) in [POS Printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-printer).

Comment: Please refer to [PointOfService Hardware support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-device-support#receipt-printer-posprinter) for up to date information on printer support.

Comment: Is this still not supported in Universal Windows Apps . Trying to run the sample for PosPrinter against a USB connected printer and its not getting detected

Answer (score 2):

The USB receipt printer works on the latest version of Windows 10 (OS Build: 16299.431).

we need to install the **OPOS ADK** to create POS receipt printer, which is available at the windows folder of printer driver( path: PRINTER\Windows\OPOS ADK). After installing the OPOS ADK setup we have to create the POS printer by using the **EPSON OPOS ADK SetupPOS**.

*I have explained about how to create POS printer using EPSON OPOS ADK SetupPOS using the following screen shots:*

**Step 1:**
Righ click on the POSPrinter and select Add New Device.

[image]

**Setp 2:** Press Next

[image]

**Step 3:**
Click Check Health Interactive and Press Start it will give the “OPOS SUCCESS” messgae as in the screen shot. Then restart the system You have configured the Receipt printer successfully and you can start printing.

[image]